# How to get flexed child to take up 100% height

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I can't make the checkbox div take up 100% height as seen with the code/fiddle below. As you can see from the second child, the height is at 100% (hover doesn't take up 100% of the height), but I'd also like the first child to be at 100% height. How do I achieve this?

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/s3hdx14u/

Code for future reference (not usable due to scss)

```css
ul {
    &.content {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    li {
        align-items: center;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        overflow: auto;

        & + li {
            border-top: 5px solid black;
        }

        div.checkbox {
            height: 100%;
            flex: 1;
            align-items: stretch;
            flex-shrink: 0;
            &:hover {
                background-color: green;
            }
            input[type=checkbox] {
    
            }
        }

        div.container {
            padding: 10px;
            width: 100%;
            &:hover {
                background-color: lighten(lightblue, 10%);
                cursor: pointer;
            }
        }

        header {
            font-size: 125%;
            font-weight: bold;
            .small {
                font-size: 80%;
                font-weight: normal;
            }
        }        
    }
}
```

```html
        <ul class="content">
            <li 
                v-for="(result, key) in results" 
                :key="key"
            >
                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input 
                        type="checkbox" 
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                  content<br>
                  content<br>
                  content<br>
                  content<br>                  
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be achieved by making a few adjustments to your SCSS. First, you can remove the following rules from `div.checkbox`, and add `display:flex`

```
div.checkbox {
    // height: 100%;
    // flex: 1;
    // align-items: stretch;
    // flex-shrink: 0;

    display:flex; // Add this

    ...
}
```

By adding the `display:flex` rule to the `div.checkbox`, this gives us flex-based control over the vertical placement of any of it's child elements.

Lastly, we want to actually want the checkbox to center vertically in the `div.checkbox`. To do this, we can add the `align-self` rule to `input[type=checkbox]` as follows:

```
input[type=checkbox] {    
    align-self: center; // Add this
}
```

For a working example, [see this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s3hdx14u/5/) - hope that helps!

Comment: kinda strange how it won't fill up the height.